# Is it possible to copy testing results from 7 Zip?

Tags: windows-7

I have some 200,000 .cbr .cbz and other compressed files which I'm testing with 7 zip.
So far I'm getting a lot of CRC failed files so I'd like to copy and paste the
results so I can check all the files.

Answer (score 2):

Run it from the command line:

```
7z t "blah.zip"

7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: blah.zip

Testing     blah.txt

Everything is Ok

Size:       417220
Compressed: 66087
```

(Numbers and name made up)

But actually, run it from the command line and redirect the output to a file:

```
7z t "blah.zip" >> results.txt
```

Then when you're done, search for whatever the errors are - if the error message contains CRC errors, you'd run something like find /I "crc" results.txt

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why the dialog itself is unselectable, otherwise the GUI version would have worked too.